# How to get Color Depth and Bit Depth from an Image Android

Tags: android, image, color-depth, bit-depth

I have been trying for some days to find the **Color depth** and/or **Bit depth** of any already available image (jpeg,png format preferable) in SD card for Android.

I have not been able to get any breakthrough till now.

I want output to be accordingly like 8 bit,16 bit,24 bit,32 bit...

Yes it should be inclusive of the R,G,B pattern.

I have stumbled upon [A Java class to determine image width, height and color depth for a number of image file formats. Written by Marco Schmidt](https://gist.github.com/janih/4536956)

Any guidance is welcomed.

Comment: Did you find a way?

Comment: Nope, was not able to find any way.